# Android softkeyboard hiddin other elements?

Tags: android, keyboard, textedit

my app screen first picture

when i fist open soft keyboard picture in the middle

and then I close the keyboard and open again and the keyboard is hiding elements. picture on the right.

how to fix this? I want my keyboard always to open like the first time

http://postimg.org/image/ufw3v45in/

thanks for the time. Sorry if a am breaking some rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define windowSoftInputMode in manifest file for different mode for activity like :-

```
<activity
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in the manifest add this tag to activity.for more details 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

```
<activity
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
```